# if statement within awk script

Tags: if-statement, awk

I have two files: `$wrkfile` and `$mapfile`.  I need to look at $5 in $wrkfile and IF $5 == "2R" then I need to pull the new rate from $2 in $mapfile and write that into $5 in $wrkfile.  If $5 = "2R" then do nothing and next.

Below is an an example of `$wrkfile`, `$mapfile`, and `$expected`.  I have also included the `awk` script I am using that is failing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{ if ( $5 == "2R" ) {print($1,$2,$3,$4,a[$1],$6} else  
{print($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6} }' OFS="|" "$mapfile" "$wrkfile" > "$output"


$wrkfile
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000050.00|

$mapfile
12345678912|9.00|
12345678914|10.00| 
12345678993|11.00|
12345678983|12.00| 
12345678963|13.00|
12345678917|14.00|

$expected
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
```

Comment: When `|` is the delimiter, the fields end with blanks, so `"2R"` is not equal to `"2R  "`, etc.

Comment: Since none of the entries in `$wrkfile` contain `2R`, it isn't clear why any of them got mapped in the expected output.

Comment: there are other issues as well.  Your RATE column has two decimal dots and NEW RATE doesn't match the format.  If condition should check $3 not $5 based on expected output format.  Also there are 6 columns in the output not 5.

Comment: No, i need $5, but was thinking I could use printf and %9d to format the output.....my main issue getting my IF statement to work........

Comment: my example files above contain headers or which the live work data does not.  I will edit accordingly.....thank you @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your new input and output files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
$5=="2R" { $6 = sprintf("%0*.2f",length($6),map[$1]) }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk mapfile wrkfile
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|01|000000050.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
12345678912|C|01|A|2R|000000009.00|
```

Comment: Sorry! I did mention above that i was removing the headers.  You hvae been very helpful.  $6 in $wrkfile is a pay rate, right justified, in format 000000000.00.

Comment: confusion removed....sorry, i didnt even see that when i was makign example files.  I could not post originals as the contained SSN's......

Comment: ok, I edited my answer to just show the script+output for your new input files format.

Answer (score 0):

I modified some input entries to get a some matches, your code can be changed as

```
$ awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
           NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} 
           $3~/2R/{$6=a[$1]} 
                  1' mapfile wrkfile

EMPLID     |TYPE1|REC|TYPE2|CODE|RATE        |
12345678912|C    |01 |A    |01  |000000.50.00|
12345678912|C    |01 |A    |01  |000000.50.00|
12345678912|C    |01 |A    |01  |000000.50.00|
12345678912|C    |2R |A    |01  |9.00    |
12345678912|C    |2R |A    |01  |9.00    |
12345678912|C    |2R |A    |01  |9.00    |
12345678912|C    |2R |A    |01  |9.00    |
12345678912|C    |2R |A    |01  |9.00    |
```

formatting the last column is possible but I'm not sure what the double decimal points mean.

Comment: be careful with that as the unanchored regexp means 2R in one file will match 12R or various other strings in another.

Comment: @EdMorton - might you be able to assist? You helped me on my last post and it worked perfectly.